# Question about permute-by-sorting

Tags: java, algorithm

In the book "Introduction to Algorithms", second edition, there is the following problem:

Suppose we have some array:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4}
```

and some random priorities array:

```
P = {36,3,97,19}
```

and the goal is to permute the array `a` randomly using this priorities array.

This is the pseudo code:

```
PERMUTE-BY-SORTING (A)
1 n ← length[A]
2 for i ← 1 to n
3      do P[i] = RANDOM (1, n 3)
4 sort A, using P as sort keys
5 return A
```

The result should be the permuted array:

```
B={2, 4, 1, 3};
```

I have written this code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Permute {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int a[] = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
        int n = a.length;
        int b[] = new int[a.length];
        int p[] = new int[a.length];
        for (int i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
            p[i] = r.nextInt(n*n*n) + 1;
        }

        // for (int i=0;i<p.length;i++){
        // System.out.println(p[i]);
        //}
    }
}
```

How do I continue?

Comment: What are you asking? Do you not understand how the result is attained? Do you not understand how to write the code to attain the result? What?

Comment: how result is attained  i dont understand

Comment: Please note that it's strongly discouraged to post homework questions and just ask for a solution. That's not the point of homework, and disrespectful to other users. Please explain how far you got with your solution, and where exactly you got stuck; then you'll probably get help.

Comment: Also see info about homework questions:

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: As to your question: Do you understand the problem posed? Do you understand why the result given is the right one? Or is your question about the pseudo-code?

Comment: i understand question i know how it got B array just wanted understand how write code

Comment: yes problem i understand

Comment: i need code how to implement it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which part you're having trouble with, but essentially this is what happened:

```
int[] a = {  1,  2,  3,  4 };
int[] p = { 36,  3, 97, 19 };
```

However you think about it, essentially we want to "zip" the elements of these two lists together. So at the abstract level, we have the following:

```
Pair<int,int> zipped = { ( 1,36), ( 2, 3), ( 3,97), ( 4,19) };
```

Now we sort `zipped` by the second value in the `Pair`. Whatever sorting algorithm works; it doesn't really matter.

```
zipped = { ( 2, 3), ( 4,19), ( 1,36), ( 3,97) };
```

We then unzip the pairs to get the permuted `a`:

```
a = {  2,  4,  1,  3 };
p = {  3, 19, 36, 97 };
```

---

#### How to implement

The zip-into-`Pair`-then-unzip works just fine. Otherwise, you can modify the sorting algorithm so that whenever it moves elements of `p[i]` to `p[j]`, it also moves `a[i]` to `a[j]` to keep both arrays "in-sync".

---

#### Java snippet

In the following snippet, the `priorities` array is hardcoded to the above values. You already figured out how to seed it with random numbers.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PermuteBySorting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class PrioritizedValue<T> implements Comparable<PrioritizedValue<T>> {
            final T value;
            final int priority;
            PrioritizedValue(T value, int priority) {
                this.value = value;
                this.priority = priority;
            }
            @Override public int compareTo(PrioritizedValue other) {
                return Integer.valueOf(this.priority).compareTo(other.priority);
            }           
        }
        int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int[] priorities = { 36, 3, 97, 19 };
        final int N = nums.length;
        List<PrioritizedValue<Integer>> list =
            new ArrayList<PrioritizedValue<Integer>>(N);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            list.add(new PrioritizedValue<Integer>(nums[i], priorities[i]));
        }
        Collections.sort(list);
        int[] permuted = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            permuted[i] = list.get(i).value;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(permuted));
        // prints "[2, 4, 1, 3]"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks polygenelubricants but  does not exist  more simple algorithm ?i think it is very big code then it is necessary

Comment: This is a clean solution, sure a simpler one does exist but in this case I don't think it should be preferred.

Comment: @davit: You can always just use `Collections.shuffle`.